# How to map array as key value using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to sort a json array value as ker same key value using PHP. My code is below.

```
echo json_encode( $output );

// Output:
[
    {
        "first_name":"robin",
        "last_name":"sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper_code":"BA001"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"robin",
        "last_name":"sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper_code":"BA002"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"Rama",
        "last_name":"Nayidu",
        "reg_no":13,
        "paper_code":"BA001"
    }
];
```

The above is my array list. Here I need to sort the all row value by `reg_no` means if there are multiple rows including same `reg_no` then those will meagre with  joining the both name and my expected output should like below.

**expected output:**

```
[
    {
        'name':"robin sahoo",
        "reg_no":12,
        "paper1":"BA001",
        "paper2":"BA002",
        "paper3":"",
        "paper4":""
    },
    {
        'name':"Rama Nayidu",
        "reg_no":13,
        "paper1":"BA001",
        "paper2":"",
        "paper3":"",
        "paper4":""
    }
]
```

Here `paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4` will be selected serially means suppose same `reg_no=12` has first row `paper_code= BA001` then it will be `paper1=BA001` and second row `paper_code=BA002` then it will be `paper2=BA002` and so on. Here I am using PHP to map this array.

Comment: Cf. http://php.net/array-multisort example #3

Comment: There are also some extra key-value pair should be added in output array.

Comment: `$output=[{"first_name":"robin"...` is not valid PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : I am writing just output array format.

Comment: You should change question to "How to sort an array ordering with a nested value" or search for this kind of examples

Comment: You should also make an attempt of solving this yourself first. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @Riccardo the question isn't about sorting but about modifying the data structure to group related data together

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly this might be a solution:

```
<?php

//defining source
$array[0]['first_name']='robin';
$array[0]['last_name']='sahoo';
$array[0]['reg_no']=12;
$array[0]['paper_code']='BA001';

$array[1]['first_name']='robin';
$array[1]['last_name']='sahoo';
$array[1]['reg_no']=12;
$array[1]['paper_code']='BA002';

$array[2]['first_name']='Rama';
$array[2]['last_name']='Nayidu';
$array[2]['reg_no']=13;
$array[2]['paper_code']='BA001';

//var_dump($array)
echo json_encode($array);

//avoid warnings
$reg_no = array();

//loop through source array
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  //saving used reg_no
  $this_reg_no = $value['reg_no'];
  if(!isset($reg_no[$this_reg_no])){
    //it's the first time I meet $this_reg_no
    //add it to the known reg_no and save his key
    $reg_no[$this_reg_no]=$key;
    $result[$key]['name'] = $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'];
    $result[$key]['reg_no'] = $value['reg_no'];
    $result[$key]['paper1'] = $value['paper_code'];
    //in $papers_count I count the number of paper_code saved.
    //the key is the same index as in $result while the value is the counter for that reg_no
    $papers_count[$key] = 1;
  }
  else{
    //I met $this_reg_no already, update existing key
    $papers_count[$reg_no[$this_reg_no]]++;
    $result[$reg_no[$this_reg_no]]['paper'.$papers_count[$reg_no[$this_reg_no]]] = $value['paper_code'];
  }
}

//var_dump($result)
echo json_encode($result);


 ?>
```

result:

```
[{"first_name":"robin","last_name":"sahoo","reg_no":12,"paper_code":"BA001"},{"first_name":"robin","last_name":"sahoo","reg_no":12,"paper_code":"BA002"},{"first_name":"Rama","last_name":"Nayidu","reg_no":13,"paper_code":"BA001"}]{"0":{"name":"robin sahoo","reg_no":12,"paper1":"BA001","paper2":"BA002"},"2":{"name":"Rama Nayidu","reg_no":13,"paper1":"BA001"}}
```